# How to translate "Self-Isolation" and "Garden-Conversation" to Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

As new terminology enters the public lexicon how would some of these be expressed in Latin?

Self-Isolation: from segrego with a reflexive pronoun: "se segregat" = "he isolates himself.

The reflexive pronoun can be strengthened with an intensifier, a part of "ipse" = "self";

"me (ipsum) segrego" = "I isolate myself".

A perfect participle passive: "segregatus" = "(having been) isolated"

Alternatively, from "exsilium" = "exile", the diminutive: "exiliunculus" = "little exile"; "little", because unlike a real exile, the "victim"/ patient is confined in his own home.

Personal Protection Equipment (PPE): with delightful simplicity the Romans might well have used "armatura" (feminine noun) = armour, as a similie: "This functions as armour, (haec agit quasi armaturam) against the pestilence." 
Alternatively, adjective "armatus" = armed; equipped; fortified (contra morbum). Also "arma" (neuter plural noun): armour; shields; equipment (military) [Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict.].

Garden Conversation: friends and relatives may now speak at measured distance: one at the front door; other, at garden gate;

using "colloquium" (neuter noun): "colloquium veride" = "a green conversation";

or, "sermo" (masculine noun): "sermo herbidus" = "a grassy conversation".

Any thoughts, ideas or improvements?

Comment: Where does the term "Garden Conversation" come from? I have not heard the term before.

Comment: @Nickimite: First heard this last Tuesday. Had to ask this friend what she meant. It's one of the newest of the new. We're on the cutting edge of the evolution of English.

Comment: Perhaps something more established in the direction of "Garden Conversation" could be derived from the story of Pyramus and Thisbe?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Yes, if people speak to each other through a wall, it would keep both parties safe from the pestilence.

Answer (score 1):

How about the adjective **hortensis** or **hortensius** for "garden", or the phrase **per hortum** to emphasize that the garden serves as a separation, rather than a surrounding? So, e.g. **colloquium hortense** or **sermo per hortum**?